# Arcpy Cursor error needs more specifics

Tags: arcpy, cursor

When I us a cursor on a table and get a column that doesn't exist error as follows:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'P:\csvExample.csv', ["ID", "example", 'long list of other headers']) as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         print row[1]
...         
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
```

I would like to know which specific field(s) were specified that don't exist.  In this example, the field 'example' should actually be 'Example' to match the header name in the file.  I would like to either add my own error or in some way extract the information that it is the specific field 'example' that is creating this issue.  Any elegant ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to check the fields beforehand:

```
existingFieldNames = [x.name for x in arcpy.ListFields(r'P:\csvExample.csv')]
for f in cursorFields:
    if f not in existingFieldNames:
        print "field %s not found in csvFile" % f
```

however, I'm wondering if a more elegant solution exists, or if some way exists to extract the specific field from the error the cursor throws.

Comment: `set(cursorFields) - set(existingFieldNames)` would return the items in the cursor list that are not in the table.

Comment: Might want to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @Bjorn hat is a nice trick.  Paul, making it case insensitive would raise false negatives because arc's cursors are themselves case sensitve.